# What does C's unary '&' do? Why doesn't it work on constants?

Tags: c, pointers, unary-operator

I am trying to make a new programming language, and I am trying to add the `&` (pointer-to) operator from C. What exactly does it do? That is, how does it 'create' a pointer? Why can't it create a pointer to a constant<sup>1</sup>? My current implementation of the operator is as follows, but it also works on constants, so I assume it is not how the C operator works:

```
operator & (any one argument):
    temp = allocate (typeof argument)
    store argument in temp
    return temp
```

<sup>1</sup>: example program:

```c
int main(){
    int* x;
    x = &1;
}
```

`gcc` output:

```
ptr.c: In function ‘main’:
ptr.c:3:6: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
  x = &1;
```

Comment: It doesn't create a pointer.  It provides the address of the object to which it is applied.

Comment: What you've implemented is roughly "boxing" in C# (converting value type to reference type)... Side note: "make a new programming language" is not an excuse not to read about existing languages yourself)

Comment: @William I see. That's my mistake.

Comment: @Alexei ok. I didn't know where to look. Sorry.

Comment: In your language, if I do `int a = 5; int *b = &a; *b = 6;` a doesn't get set to 6? That seems like it defeats the whole purpose of pointers then, doesn't it?

Comment: @immibis Ah, that is what I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C's unary `&` gives you the address of the thing it's applied to.

So for example, `&x` gives the address of `x`.

It doesn't create a new variable, copy x into that variable and then return the address of the new variable. It returns the address of `x`, plain and simple.

Answer (score 1):

> What does C's unary '&' do? Why doesn't it work on constants?

Because the language does not allow it.

C *could* allow `&1` as in  other languages such as the new language `.NoOneIsHere`.  Simply the C standard has nor seen the benefit to do so.  There is no  technical reason to not, just scant reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

& usually as a quote type, used to take a value address, b = &b, b equal b`s address for example.